# How do I change the start-up login screen desktop background and theme on a XP machine where users log-in through AD?

Tags: active-directory, windows-xp, remote-desktop

So I have this XP machine on the AD and people login to it remotely using RDP clients. There is a default looking 'HP' themed wallpaper and the default XP theme is used (blue fisher price theme). Once the user logs in then the theme and wallpaper become whatever they set it to.

Is there a way to change that start-up screen?

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement Group Policies in Active Directory

First, Create a jpg file you want as logon screen background which should be less than 256kb, name it as backgroundDefault.jpg and place it inside a server share, ex. \servername\share\backgroundDefault.jpg

You'll need to change three registry keys, instead of adding file as Background image. But the image on shared server should be .bmp and less than 256kb.

In the Group Policy Management Console, edit the GPO to change following settings.
Computer Configuration => Preferences => Windows Settings => Files => New File 
set the parameters as following image.

[image]
[image]
[image]

You should now be having your Background Logon changed.